# How can I add multiple addresses of single user in MySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

i need help. I want to have two tables in database. One is USER n othetis ADDRESS. I want to add multiple addresses for the user that is added in USER table. How can i do this ? Thank you.

Comment: You need to add user id in address table , and for fetching you need right join query

Comment: What did you try so for?

Comment: How is your HTML structured? How do you write ANYTHING to the database at the moment? If you give us that + what you have already tried, we *could* give you a sample code you could test.

Comment: actually i have just made two tables in database and was performing join query. But when i realised i need to add multiple addresses in address table for a single user in USER table so i got confused . That's why i asked here

Answer (score 3):

**1st :** You can add user unique id in address table .

**2nd :** And also maintain auto_increment primary key in address table why means when your going to edit the address means you need to update the right one so it's useful in future so maintain one column for that .

Answer (score 2):

You Have two different tables:

1) USER

2) ADDRESS

Give foreign key for ID of user table to address table

Example:

**USER**

```
id    name    email
1     abc     xxx@xxx.com
```

**ADDRESS**

```
id    user_id      address detail
1      1          address detail 1
2      1          address detail 2
```

Here user 1 has 2 address. You can add more address also

Answer (score 0):

According to the my opinion its just simple. Its one to many relationship of two tables. you can set user id as a foreign key of address table and add addresses. user id is the primary key of user table.

Answer (score 0):

The ADDRESS table should have a many-to-one relationship with the USER table and contain USER_ID as a foreign key.  Simply create multiple ADDRESS records that all have the same USER_ID.  To differentiate them you should add a field to specify the type of address such as home, business, etc.

```
USER
ID, NAME, ...

ADDRESS
ID, USER_ID, ADDRESS_TYPE, STREET, ...
```

You should also really create separate tables for ADDRESS_TYPE, CITY, COUNTRY, STATE, etc. to avoid unnecessarily duplicated data and the problems that occur when those fields are allowed to be just entered as text - e.g. Montreal, montreal, MONTREAL, mtl, Montréal are all valid ways people write the same city.

Answer (score 0):

you only need to create one table called ADDRESS:

```
CREATE TABLE ADDRESS(id int not null,user_id int,address varchar(255),PRIMARY KEY (id),FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES USER(user_id));
```