# Foreign key issue in mysql?

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, primary-key

Lets say **EmployeeId** is acting as a **primary key** in one table in a mysql database.  How to make that **EmployeeId** act as **Foreign key** in another table?

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html

Comment: Read: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45748595/how-can-i-add-multiple-addresses-of-single-user-in-mysql-database

Comment: Please google many variations of your question before asking, this is a faq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is simple question  to be answered to oneself . 
let's say you have 'employee' table 
making employeeID as primary key you are storing, updating , and deleting data from your 'employee' table . but in case you want to provide salary to any employee and you want to store that salary information in the database , in this case you need 'salary' table , where employeeID will work as foreign key

```
'employee' table 
employeeID | employee_name| employee_birthdate| address 
1          |  John due    | 1990-01-01        | Dhaka 
2          | Rahim        | 1990-02-06        | Feni,Bangladesh

'salary' table 
salaryID | employeeID(from 'employee' table | salary | date time
1        | 2                                | $5000  | 2017-04-01
2        | 2                                | $5000  | 2017-05-01
```

I hope you understand . if it still seems dozy to you , feel free to ask me anyway

Comment: Great . glad to hear that

Comment: @Rajat Then accept this answer. This lets others know the question has been answered and those that may find this question later know which answer solved this problem